# Python3 Make a list that increments for a certain amount, decrements for a certain amount

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I have the following:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...]` how can I reorder the list (actually make a new copy of the list) and then fill it as such:

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 11, 12, 13...]`

I.e. Every five iterations, the list starts to decrement, or increment.  The reason I want to do this is that I have a list of objects, and I want to fill a new list with the objects in a different order.

One technique I tried is:

```
copied_icons = [{key:'Object1'}, {key:'Object2'}, {key:'Object3'}...] 
reversed_copied_icons = copied_icons[::-1]
left_to_right = []


for h in range(17):
    left_to_right.append(copied_icons[h])

for j in range(18, 35):
    left_to_right.append(reversed_copied_icons[j])

for k in range(36, 53):
    left_to_right.append(copied_icons[k])

for l in range(54, 71):
    left_to_right.append(reversed_copied_icons[l])
```

But for some reason this returns the list out of order and duplicates some of the objects.  I am wondering if there is a simpler way to alternating incrementing and decrementing while filling my list.

Comment: so you have a list of items you want to randomly spread around?

Comment: Not spread around.  Basically I want to fill my new list with the first 10 items of the old list (in order, 0 - 9) and then fill my new list with the next 10 items (in reverse order, 19-10) and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach:

1. You are reversing the *entire* list, not just that slice. Let's say the list is `[1,2,3,4]`, and we want to reverse the second half, i.e. get `[1,2,4,3]`; with your approach, you would take the third and fourth element from the reversed list, `[4,3,2,1]`, and end up with `[1,2,2,1]`
2. The to-index in a range is exclusive, thus by using `range(17)` and then `range(18,35)` and so forth, you are missing out on the elements at index `17`, `35`, and `53`

You can use a loop for the different parts to be reversed, and then replace that slice of the list with the same slice in reverse order.

```
lst = list(range(20))
for start in range(5, len(lst), 10):
    lst[start:start+5] = lst[start+4:start-1:-1]
```

Or this way, as pointed out in comments, which also gets rid of those nasty off-by-one indices:

```
for start in range(5, len(lst), 10):
    lst[start:start+5] = reversed(lst[start:start+5])
```

Afterwards, `lst` is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15]`.

Or, in case the intervals to be reversed are irregular (as it seems to be in your question):

```
reverse = [(3, 7), (12,17)]
for start, end in reverse:
    lst[start:end] = reversed(lst[start:end])
```

Comment: It may be more readable to use `reversed(lst[start:start+5])`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the suggestion, added this to my answer. Python has so many great builtin functions, I know only half of them half as good as they'd deserve. :-)

Comment: @tobias_k you could even just create the slices once if you wanted, eg: `for slc in (slice(*el) for el in reverse): lst[slc] = reversed(lst[slc])`

Comment: @JonClements Another of those rarely used but useful builtins.... however, I'd rather make this a separate line, so it's more explicit, i.e. `slc = slice(start, end)`

Comment: @tobias_k I probably wouldn't even bother with it... I was just throwing it in there regarding your *Python has so many great builtin functions, I know only half of them half as good as they'd deserve.* :p

Comment: I get the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 2, in <module>
    lst[start:start+5] = reversed(lst[start:start+5])
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @Startec In Python3, `range` returns not a list, but an iterator. To turn it into a list, just do `list(range(20))`.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to accomplish your objective:

```
def foo(lst, n=5):
    """ lst=list to be re-ordered, n=item count before reversal """
    new_list = list()
    direction = 1
    start = 0
    end = start
    while start < len(lst):  
        # process through the list in steps of 'n', 
        # except use min for possible stub at end.
        end = start + min(n, len(lst) - start)  # i.e. start+5
        # If direction is 1, append list to new list. Otherwise, append reversed list.
        new_list[start:end] = lst[start:end][::direction]
        direction *= -1  # Switch directions
        start = end  # Jump to new starting position.
    return new_list

lst = np.arange(20).tolist()
foo(lst,5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15]
```

If the direction *= -1 line where to be removed, the code would simply copy the existing list (lst) in chunks of size 'n', the number of items you'd like before reversing the list.

Just above where the direction is to be changed, the [::direction] will be either [::1] in which case the list will be sorted in regular order or else [::-1] in which case the list will be reversed  for the chunk of size n which is being processed.  The third argument when slicing a list is the 'step size' argument, so a step of -1 returns a copy of the list in reverse order.

In case there is a stub, i.e. your stub is 2 if your list has 22 elements but your 'n' is in steps of 5, then you need to adjust your step size 'n' so you don't go past the end of your list.  The min(n, len(lst) - start) will ensure you don't go past the end of the list.  Alternatively, and probably clearer, you could use end = min(start + n, len(lst)).

Comment: While this answer is probably right, could you add an explanation of what the code does? If you look at the other answer, you can see that the explain the lines that might be difficult to understand. In your case, this would probably be `end = ...` and `new_list[...] ...`, which aren't easily understandable at first glance.

Comment: I agree with @KevinBrown, also, where does the `last` come from (line 7)?